# How to make sidebar fixed?

Tags: position, fixed, sidebar

How do I make my side bar fixed so when scrolling down on the page the sidebar will follow like my main menu ? I tried using a z-index to fixed the position but it doesn't work. Does any one know how to fixed that ?

This is my [site](http://alskadehem.se/blogg/)

And its ther anyone to make the sidebar fixed on ONLY blogg page and "senaste nummret" page? dont want them to be fixed on all the other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sidebar-left {left: 0px; top: 20px; padding: 0px; position:fixed;}
```

You need to define where you want the sidebar to be fixed in relation to. Hence the left: 0px and top: 20px. If you want it fixed relative to the header, footer or rhs, just change the 'left' for the correct position.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it did help! but with left:0px and padding:0px the sidebar is in left over the content. Do i have to putt 300px in left? Please see the edit on my question

Comment: Which CMS are you using? Blogger or Wordpress or something else? You need to have different css rules for different page templates so use div classes like sidebar-main ; sidebar-senaste ; sidebar-blogg (if two pages use the same template, you just need one css rule to cover them both). Use the 'inspect element' tool in your browser to fine tune the distance from the left in px that you need to get your sidebar where you need it. Without seeing your demo page, it is hard to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Iam using wordpress. that did answer my question perfectly! when I put an top 20 px the sidebar keeps being in top even when im not scrolling? Do you know what I mean. Cant save the changes because the side its live.

Comment: Using position: fixed; and top: 20px; the sidebar will always be 20px from the top no matter where you scroll. I may have misunderstood what it is that you are asking for. Perhaps this link will be of use to you in explaining different options: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp ... If you have a live site but need to make structural changes, I would suggest having a test site too. If possible, set up a second wordpress account on a subdomain and use some dummy posts to fill out the content so that you can edit your theme without worrying about your readers seeing it.